# Como faço o "while" se repetir 4 vezes apenas e quebrar pro próximo comando em C?

Tags: c, algoritmo, condição

```
int numeros, calculo, soma;
    numeros = 0;
    calculo = 0;


    while (calculo > 0) {
        printf("Digite o número: ");
        scanf("%d", &numeros);
        calculo++;
    }
soma = calculo + soma;
printf("A soma entre os valores digitados é de: %d", soma);
```

Eu quero fazer com que o `while` se repita apenas 4 vezes fazendo a pergunta "Digite um número" recebendo um valor e depois somando esses números e mostrando o valor na tela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem alguns erros neste código. Eu acho até que deveria usar um `for` neste caso, mas pode ser que tenha sido exigido usar um `while`.

Organizei e dei nomes mais significativos para as variáveis. A soma não está dentro do laço então não está somando em cada passo que pega um novo número.

A soma não foi inicializada com 0 então pode pegar um valor aleatório na memória e em alguns casos dar muito errado, não em todos, e isso é a pior parte.

A condição não está verificando se a contagem está indo até 4.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int contador = 0, soma = 0;
    while (contador < 4) {
        int numero;
        printf("Digite o número: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        contador++;
        soma += numero;
    }
    printf("A soma entre os valores digitados é de: %d", soma);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fQ4LAW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/LoopSumc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/LoopSum.c).

Comment: Funcionou obg. E sim, é obrigatório o uso de While, infelizmente kk.

Comment: Veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

quando você colocar calculo++ significa somar 1 ao valor atual de calculo, ou seja,

```
calculo=0;
calculo++; //calculo passa a valer 1
```

no codigo que você mostrou a utilização do ++ ta incorreta, ele nao vai armazenar soma dos numeros assim, na verdade, pra armazenar a soma o correto seria:

```
soma= soma + numeros;
```

ou

```
soma+=numeros;
```